# check for object list if two objects which are having all the property values

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have list of objects (`List<Text>`) with an object structure looks like as below,

```
public class Text
{
    public double? AValue { get; set; }
    public double? BValue{ get; set; }
    public double? CValue{ get; set; }
}
```

I need to check if the list of object count not to exceed `one` if we have the object that is holding that has `AValue` and i need to throw exception if more than one found

Sample valid list objects are

```
       var textList= new List<Text> // this is valid because it does not have objects which are holding BValue and CValue
        {
            new Text{ AValue = 34}
        }   

       var textList= new List<Text> // this is valid because it does not have and object that is holding `Avalue` property
        {
            new Text{ BValue = 78, Cvalue= 6},
            new Text{ BValue = 2, Cvalue= 4}
        }
```

Invalid Objects are

```
      var textList= new List<Text>  // it is invalid because it is having both objects having `AValue` property and `BValue` and `CValue` property      
        {
            new Text{ AValue = 55},
            new Text{ BValue = 66, Cvalue=77}
        }
```

In invalid object case i need to through the exception

and i am checking like this and obviously it is wrong

```
       if(textList.Count(a => a.AValue.Value != default) > 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("message");
        }
```

Could any one please let me know how can i achieve the same

Comment: @.EnigmaState Same text, same code, same question = ?. Not even want to read one like the other.

Comment: no its not about duplicates , i need to throw an error if i found two text objects, one is having Avalue and other is having BValue and CValue.

Comment: @OlivierRogier , please let me know if it is still not clear to you, that is why i added extra text here

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I updated my answer.
After talking with OP, I think I understood the problem wrong at first.

The problem is, the OP has a List of Text with nullable props.
However, the lists items should all have the same values set.
We can check the lists items set property count by checking each property for a null value, for each item.
At first we just take the first item as a reference on how many set properties we expect. Then we can iterate the list and check if any entities do not match the set properties count.

```
 var textList = new List<Text>
        {
            new Text{ AValue = 34, BValue = 23 },
            new Text{ AValue = 24, BValue = 32 },
            new Text{ AValue = 32, BValue = 42 },
            new Text{ AValue = 23, BValue = 11 },
        }; // This List is valid

 var textList2 = new List<Text>
        {
            new Text{ AValue = 34, BValue = 23 },
            new Text{ AValue = 24, BValue = 32 },
            new Text{ AValue = 32 },
            new Text{ AValue = 23, BValue = 11 },
        }; // This List is not valid

        var numValuesSet = textList.FirstOrDefault()?.GetNumValuesSet() ?? 0;
        if (textList.Count(x => x.GetNumValuesSet() != numValuesSet) > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    

    public class Text
    {
        private static System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] _properties = typeof(Text).GetProperties(); // Gets properties of type text (this type) and saves it

        public double? AValue { get; set; }
        public double? BValue { get; set; }
        public double? CValue { get; set; }

        public int GetNumValuesSet()
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var prop in _properties)
            {
                if (prop.GetValue(this) != null) // Iterates all properties of this object and checks if it is null, if not we count up
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
```

Is this correct?

Comment: i just need only boolean variable how can i get it

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: and this condition is still valid `CValue.HasValue() && BValue.HasValue()`

Comment: Instead of `Select` you can use [`All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all). `bool valid = MyList.All(x => x.IsValid());` This will return `true` if all the items in `MyList` are valid. If `MyList` is empty, it will also return `true`.

Comment: it is failing for some other conditions

Comment: i am looking for list which is having this `var textList= new List<Text>    
        {
            new Text{ AValue = 55},
            new Text{ BValue = 66, Cvalue=77}
        }`  then x => x.IsValid() should return false

Comment: i am not getting that and could not be able to through exception

Comment: Could you please help on this, it just comparing one object with previous object

Comment: @Zokka is there any other way to check this using an aggregate

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your problem/goal. So you are looking to compare each object in the list, if all objects have the same values (AValue, BValue, CValue) set. So for example, a list should only be valid if all objects have the same values set: `new List<Text> { new { AValue = 55 }, new { BValue = 66,  CValue =77 } }` is `false`. but `new List<Text> { new { BValue = 55 }, new { BValue = 66 } }` is `true` ?

Comment: sorry, its not about the same values, its about the object value nullability check

Comment: consider two objects in list any of object is having Avalue is not null and other object or the same object having BValue and Cvalue not nulls then i need to throw an exception

Comment: I updated my answer, please check if that meets your needs

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to create your own List class based on List to override the `Add` method.

```
public class Testing
{
    public double? AValue { get; set; }
    public double? BValue { get; set; }
    public double? CValue { get; set; }
}

public class MyList<Testing> : List<Testing>
{
    public new void Add(Testing item)
    {
        if (this != null && this.Count > 0) {
            var itemNullProps = item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetValue(item, null) == null).Select(x => x.Name);
            var thisNullProps = this.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetValue(this.FirstOrDefault(), null) == null).Select(x => x.Name);

            if (itemNullProps.Except(thisNullProps).Count() > 0)
                throw new ApplicationException("Not allowed");
        }
        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

and in your implementation, you could use the constructor or the ADD methods which would check and make sure all items in the list contains the values for properties that already have values.

```
// This is valid
MyList<Testing> newListx = new MyList<Testing>()
{
    new Testing{ BValue = 78, CValue= 6},
    new Testing{ BValue = 2, CValue= 4}
};

// This, of course, will throw error
MyList<Testing> newList2 = new MyList<Testing>()
{
    new Testing{ BValue = 78},
    new Testing{ BValue = 2, CValue= 4}
};
```

.. unless i totally misread the question